# specify valid wake lock level

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

working an an app with GCM support, no problems there. But when I push the notification, the app crashes an LogCat says the following:

> 03-21 14:32:13.276: E/AndroidRuntime(4457): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.yanniks.cm_updatechecker/de.yanniks.cm_updatechecker.UpdateChecker}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must specify a valid wake lock level.

How do I define the valid wake lock level?

Please help!

Comment: Show your code where you are manipulating a `WakeLock`.

Comment: should probably read, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#newWakeLock(int, java.lang.String)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must specify one of

- [PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK)
- [FULL_WAKE_LOCK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#FULL_WAKE_LOCK)
- [SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK)
- [SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK)

when you call [newWakeLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#newWakeLock%28int,%20java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 2):

There also two extra flags:

- ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP
- ON_AFTER_RELEASE

You can use "|" with PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, FULL_WAKE_LOCK, SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK.