# Alarm service crashes

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager, alarm, android-pendingintent

I'm trying to create an alarm with a list of time to go off that I already have stored in Parse.

I have a AlarmService with this code:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    Toast.makeText(this,"onStartCommand()",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmScreenActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

    return flags;
}
```

The Service goes off after the Save Button in add an alarm activity is pressed as follow:

```
//set time into calendar instance
Calendar calendar= Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,mAlarmDetails.timeHour);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,mAlarmDetails.timeMinute);

AlarmManager reminder = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmService.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

reminder.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent);
```

When the time is met, the app crashes and my Log says:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.example......AlarmService@16859914 with Intent { flg=0x4 cmp=com.example.....AlarmService (has extras) }: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
```

I don't quite understand this log error. Can someone explain and help me solve this issue?

The Toast from the AlarmService also never appeared.

another question, do I have to initiate my service from the button? is there a way to do this without using a button? I think my app will work better if I can do this without the button since the time information is online in parse.

I also want my alarm to go off everyday. I currently have information of hour and minute. Do I need some information to tell it to go off everyday?

Thank you in advance

**UPDATE**

I added a wake lock so it will wake my phone into my Service as follow:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    Toast.makeText(this,"onStartCommand()",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    //wake lock
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON, "My Wake Log");
    mWakeLock.acquire();

    //start reminder screen
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmScreenActivity.class);
    ReminderIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);

    return flags;
}
```

Now I have another Log that says:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.example....AlarmService@129539b6 with Intent { flg=0x4 cmp=com.....AlarmService (has extras) }: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must specify a valid wake lock level.
```

What does this mean?

Comment: Did you put the alarm permission into the manifest?

Comment: no. whats the permission? I only have a wakelock. I don't think it is needed yet though.

Comment: I was able to use the service with just  toast and no alarm as a test in the begining. But after I put the alarmmanager,calender,pendingintent and such, it doesnt work

Comment: A pending intent must be received. Where did you receive it?

Comment: hmm... I believe I have no such thing. What I showed is what I have. How do I make a receiver? and how do I connect to the receiver?

Comment: see answer below. It must be registered in the manifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is your problem

```
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
```

when you want to start an activity by a non activity context you have to add `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag to the starter intent so your `onStartCommand` code would be like this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmScreenActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works really well. now the question is, based on my code, am I doing this right? It feels like what I did is way simpler then what people are doing based on my research.

Comment: oh and this alarm doesn't wake my locked screen. How do I do that?

Comment: i think that this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966506/programmatically-turn-screen-on-in-android will help you wake the screen

Comment: please look at the new update I have provided. Thank you

Comment: your welcome ! when you have faced an Exception just google about it and yo will find good sloutions . i have found this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15555630/specify-valid-wake-lock-level

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are seeing is because the `Intent` being sent to start the `Activity` is being sent from `Service`, so its `Context` has no notion of task/back stack.  The logcat shows you that you need to add the flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` to the `Intent` from the `Service` in order to get the `Activity` started.

All of that being said, you are likely still going to run into issues since the alarm is being used to start the `Service`.  If the device is asleep and the alarm expires, the system will wake long enough for the `AlarmManager` to process the alarm internally.  If the alarm's `PendingIntent` is for a `BroadcastReceiver` then it will also keep the device awake long enough so the registered receiver gets called.  It does not do the same thing if the `PendingIntent` is for a `Service` or `Activity`.  This article will help with some additional details (and sample code): http://po.st/7UpipA